# Javascript How to know , if textbox default value changed than update changed textbox value

Tags: javascript, textbox

,Hi all,

I have 15 textboxes in my main page.
For example,

CustomerTextbox value = "SomeCustomer",

CustomerTelephone value = "111111",

CustomerAdress value "ABCDE",

CustomerEmail value "info@info.com",

etc......

And ı have also "Save Change" Button.

İf ı click "Save Change" button,i update all textboxex values to my database.That is why system works slow.

How can ı know which textbox changed and only update that textbox to my database ?

As instance,

CustomerTelephone changed and ı only want to update CustomerTelephone value.

İs there something ı can do for this purpose?

Comment: browsers now support the placeholder attribute for inputs, you should use that instead of having default values

Comment: You might benefit from having something like knockout js. This has built in dependency tracking. Here is the link: http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: If 15 textbox values is slowing down your system, I would say that there might be something _really_ wrong there...